# How to perform an SQL query x minutes after another one is executed?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

How can I make information that I have put into my database self update itself after 5 minutes of inputing the data?

Say I have a table:

```
   +--+--+-----+
   |id|ip|count|
   +--+--+-----+
   | 1|..|3    |
   +--+--+-----+
```

When the count is greater than 1 I want to wait 5 minutes and then change it back to 1.

I am wanting this because I want to set a 'timeout' when a user enters there password wrong 3 or more times!

So I have wrote this code for when a user enters the wrong password:

```
$currentIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ipcheck = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *
FROM ipcheck");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ipcheck))
{
    if($currentIP == $row['ip']){
        if($row['count'] > 2){
            //attempted to log in too many times!
            header("Location: secure?err=2");
            exit;
        }else{
            $IPUsed = "YES";
        }
    }
}
if($IPUsed == "YES"){
    //They have failed to log in AGAIN!
    $updateIP = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE ipcheck 
    SET count = count + 1
    WHERE ip = '".$currentIP."'");
}else{
    //first failed login attempt
    $insertNewIp = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO ipcheck (ip)
    VALUES ('".$currentIP."')");
}
```

And that creates the table above but what would be the best method to go about doing my question? Would it be through using a cron? or maybe a MySQL Scheduled Event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually resetting the count add a timestamp column to your table indicating the time of the last attempt.

When an invalid attempt is detected compare the current time with the recorded time:

If if is more than 5 minutes old reset the count.

If it is less than 5 minutes old increment the count if it is below the threshold or block the attempt if the threshold is exceeded.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use 1 or 0 for blocked, but use a timestamp. When the user tries to login, check for the current time and compare this with the timestamp in the database